Phaser 3 how to setup collision to multiple layers
strangely enough, I am not able to setup collision on multiple layers in Phaser 3. I've setup collision for specific indexes in walls layer and everythng works but I am not able to setup collision to waterLayer as a whole. Waterlayer renders correctly and I am able to log the waterLayer properties. For some reason still, player always is able to run trough the waterlayer. Here is relevant code:
  preload() {
    // Load spritesheet for the protagonist
    this.load.spritesheet('protagonist', '/assets/mainCH.png', { frameWidth: 100, frameHeight: 100 });
    this.load.spritesheet('enemy', '/assets/waterspirit.png', { frameWidth: 150, frameHeight: 150 });
   
   
   
    
  
    // Load tileset and tilemap
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', '/assets/maps/worldmap.json');

    
    
    this.load.image('spruce', '/assets/spruce.png', { frameWidth: 150, frameHeight: 150 });
    this.load.scenePlugin('AnimatedTiles', '/phaser-animated-tiles/src/plugin/AnimatedTiles.js', 'animatedTiles', 'animatedTiles');
    this.load.image('dark_tiles', 'assets/maps/terrain_dark.png');
  }

  create() {

    //resize canvas when coming from scene-two
    const gameConfig = this.sys.game.config;
            // Create the weather effects
            this.renderer.pipelines.addPostPipeline('rainPostFX', RainFX);
            this.cameras.main.setPostPipeline(RainFX);
    

    // Resize the game canvas
    this.scale.resize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
  // Create the protagonist sprite
    this.protagonist = this.physics.add.sprite(characterPositionInWorldMap, 250, 'protagonist');
    this.protagonist.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    // Set the size and offset of the hitbox

    this.protagonist.body.setSize(hitboxWidth, hitboxHeight);
    this.protagonist.body.setOffset(hitboxOffsetX, hitboxOffsetY);
    
     // Initialize the hitbox sprite for collision detection

    this.enemy = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 100, 'enemy');
 

    // Set up properties for the water spirit
    this.enemy.speed = 100; // Adjust the speed as needed
    this.protagonist.setDepth(4);
   
    this.enemy.setDepth(1);
    const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map' });
  
    this.animatedTiles.init(map);
    this.physics.world.createDebugGraphic();

// Add the tilesets
const darkTileset = map.addTilesetImage('dark_tiles', 'dark_tiles');

// Create layers from tilemap data using different tilesets
const groundLayer = map.createLayer('Groundlayer', darkTileset, 0, 0);
const waterLayer = map.createLayer('waterlayer', darkTileset, 0, 0);
const grassLayer = map.createLayer('grass_and_tree_layer', darkTileset, 0, 0);
const stoneLayer = map.createLayer('stones_n_stuff', darkTileset, 0, 0);

// Create hut layer using the hut tileset
const hutLayer = map.createLayer('hutLayer', darkTileset, 0, 0);
const transportlayer = map.createLayer('transportlayer', darkTileset, 0, 0);
const walls = map.createLayer('walls', darkTileset, 0, 0);


    // Adjust the depth of layers as needed
    groundLayer.setDepth(1);
    waterLayer.setDepth(1);
    grassLayer.setDepth(1);
    stoneLayer.setDepth(2);
    hutLayer.setDepth(30);
    walls.setDepth(2);
    transportlayer.setDepth(2);
   
// Enable collision for the specified tile indexes
// Set collision for specified tile indexes in the waterLayer
waterIndex.forEach(index => {
  map.setCollision(index, true, this.waterLayer);
});

    collidableTileIndexes.forEach(index => {
      map.setCollision(index, true, this.walls);
  });


    // Define animations.....
  
   
    // Set up keyboard input
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
   
    this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, map.widthInPixels, map.heightInPixels);
 

 // Enable debug rendering for the tilemap layer representing water
waterLayer.renderDebug = true;
 
 this.groundLayer = groundLayer;
 this.waterLayer = waterLayer;
 this.grassLayer = grassLayer;
 this.stoneLayer = stoneLayer;
 this.hutLayer = hutLayer;
 this.walls = walls;
 this.transportlayer = transportlayer;


  // Listen for collision between protagonist and walls
  this.physics.add.collider(this.protagonist, this.walls, () => {
    // Disable movement controls for the protagonist
    //this.protagonist.setVelocity(0); // Stop the protagonist's movement
    console.log("wall hit")
    });
 // Set up collision detection between the protagonist and the waterLayer
 this.physics.add.collider(this.protagonist, this.waterLayer);
   // Set up camera to follow the player
   this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.protagonist);
this.enterHutText = this.add.text(this.protagonist.x, this.protagonist.y, 'Press f to enter the hut', { font: '24px Arial', fill: '#ffffff' });
this.enterHutText.setDepth(100);
this.physics.add.existing(this.protagonist);
this.physics.add.existing(this.waterLayer);
this.physics.add.collider(this.protagonist, this.waterLayer);

  }

  update() {
    
    // Reset velocity
    this.protagonist.setVelocity(0);
    this.physics.collide(this.protagonist, this.waterIndex, () => {
      console.log("hit");
  }, null, this);
 
   //some irrelevant logic....
   


    // Handle keyboard input......



 
    this.physics.moveToObject(this.enemy, this.protagonist, this.enemy.speed);
     // Play the appropriate animation based on the collision result





}



}


Instead of writing:
// Set up collision detection for water layer
map.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true, 'waterlayer'); // Adjust tile indexes as needed
// Set up collision detection for walls layer
map.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true, 'walls'); // Adjust tile indexes as needed

Write:
walls.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true);
waterLayer.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true);


The issue is that you are adding the water layer to the "physics world", with the line
this.physics.add.existing(this.waterLayer);

If you remove that line, it should work. Since this is not needed for the tiles/layers, Similar as the other layers in your code.
Here a short demo,...
... if this doesn't work you would have to narrow the program


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
  width: 400,
  height: 180,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: {
        y: 100
      },
      debug: false,
    }
  },
  scene: {
    create,
    update,
  },
  banner: false,
};

function create() {
  this.add.text(10, 10, 'Green Layer is configured wrong\nRed is configured correct');

  // Creating Graphics for the DEMO ->
  let graphics = this.make.graphics();
  graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
  graphics.fillRect(8, 0, 8, 8);

  graphics.generateTexture('tiles', 8 * 4, 8);
  graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
  graphics.fillRect(8, 0, 8, 8);

  graphics.generateTexture('tiles2', 8 * 4, 8);
  // Creating Graphics for the DEMO <-

  // Creating map data for the demo 
  var mapData = '00000010000'.split('').map(rowValue => rowValue.repeat(50).split(''))

  // Map1 will not be added to th physics world
  var map1 = this.make.tilemap({
    data: mapData,
    tileWidth: 8,
    tileHeight: 8
  });
  var tiles = map1.addTilesetImage('tiles');
  var layer1 = map1.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);
  layer1.setCollision(1);


  // Map2 will be added to th physics world
  var tiles2 = map1.addTilesetImage('tiles2');
  var map2 = this.make.tilemap({
    data: mapData,
    tileWidth: 8,
    tileHeight: 8
  });
  var layer2 = map2.createLayer(0, tiles2, 0, 50);
  layer2.setCollision(1);
  
  // Simple Player that just falls
  this.player = this.add.circle(16, 16, 4, 0xffffff)
    .setDepth(2);
  this.physics.add.existing(this.player);

  this.physics.add.collider(layer1, this.player);
  // following line breaks the collision logic, ...
  // ... but enables `collide` checks
  this.physics.add.existing(layer1, true);
  
  
  this.physics.add.collider(layer2, this.player);
  // following line breaks the collision logic, ...
  // ... but enables `collide` checks
  // this.physics.add.existing(layer2, true);

  this.layer1 = layer1;
  this.layer2 = layer2;

}

function update() {

  // this will work
  this.physics.collide(this.player,  this.layer1, () => {
     console.log("hit - 1");
  }, null, this);
  
  // this won't work
  this.physics.collide(this.player,  this.layer2, () => {
     console.log("hit - 2");
  }, null, this);

}

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>




btw.: you could alternatively use collideTiles, but this is a whole other can of worms.


This is some Phaser related bug it seems. When I initialize waterlayer last, then walls layer collision stops working and waterlayer collision works :D Removed the this.physics.add.existing(this.waterLayer); but it didn't fix the problem. Good suggestion though

Well there could be more bugs in your code, I just looked for the waterlayer releated part, but without running example it is hard to tell. If I have some time later on I might create a small inline demo.

@AftersunLotion I updated ma answer with a short demo, showcasing what I mean, I hope it helps.

@AftersunLotion I don't think it is a Phaser bug, it was designed to have different ways how one can use it. Especially since most of the collision official example, "use" the so
called bug.

Nice demo! Removed all the this.physics.add.existing lines. Problem seems to be related to this.physics.collide object specifically and the order matters which layer is initialized first. Layers seems to work fine and they get rendered but the collision detection works only with the layer that is initilaized last. Have to try to simplify the code and look if there is something else breaking the collision for multiple layers.

Btw.: you can pass an array to setCollision you don't have to iterate over array, this should also improve performance.

@AftersunLotion just wanted to know, do you need still some sipport, or is you issue "closed"?

It seems this collision detection problem was a syntax issue. Instead of writing: map.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true, 'waterlayer');
map.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true, 'walls'); this fixes the problem: walls.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true);
waterLayer.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true);
